# Edit to "add more useful answer"

Tags: discussion, edits, rollbacks

I stumbled upon this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2601273/199048), which looks fine on the first glance, but when you'll look at the revisions, you'll notice that for 3 years it just said "No." until someone edited it. Normally I would just rollback, but it got an enormous amount of up votes.

Arguments for rollback:

- It got 161 up votes before the edit (see [data explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/66152/show-vote-history-for-a-post?PostId=2601273)) and 96 afterwards. Therefore newer up votes could be independent of the new part.
- The new paragraph isn't related to the old version in any way, it's an independent answer.
- The edit included a solution which four other answers already suggested years before, whereas they got negative comments and down votes.

Should we rollback or not?

Comment: It may be worth noting that the original author of that answer is an active user (last seen 13 hours ago), so it's probable that he's aware of the edit and is ok with it. Otherwise he could have rolled it back himself...

Comment: @AJPerez Maybe, but... Is it right to get plenty of upvotes thanks to someone else's effort?

Comment: @Marc.2377: I don't care about his reputation points, but about the upvotes before the edit. Is this still the same answer?

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer after a quick look at the edit one can see the awnser wasn't really "changed" rather its expanded a bit from just no to no + some explaination that java doesn't have the API yet and some example

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer I agree with you, seems to me it's not. Still, this question tends to get opinion-based answers, aparently.

Comment: Is the site more or less useful with the information that is currently there or the information that was there before? There's your answer. Who got what rep and why is secondary to the usefulness of the output.

Comment: @AntP: Neither. The site with the edit is exactly as useful as without it, because there were already 4 answers, which suggested that solution. But I'll take aspillers answer, so we'll keep it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We should **keep it** as it is.

There are two potential reasons to consider a rollback here, neither of which are sufficient:

1. **Should we rollback because the editor should not have made such a drastic change?**

   Consider the edit-rejection reasons:

   > - **spam or vandalism**
   >     This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.
   > - **no improvement whatsoever**
   >     This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.
   > - **clearly conflicts with author's intent**
   >     This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.
   > - **attempt to reply**
   >     This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

   We can immediately eliminate the first two options. This is not quite an "attempt to reply," either. Thus the only option left is that the edit "*clearly conflicts with author's intent*." This might *possibly* be a valid reason to reject the edit when it is new, but after the edit has sat undisturbed by the original author (who is an active user with nearly 70k rep) for over a year, it's safe to say that the edit aligns acceptably well with the author's intent.
2. **Should we roll back because the answer has changed too drastically and no longer reflects the original content of the answer (which had been upvoted many times)?**

   While it may be wrong to *drastically* change an answer if it has gotten many upvotes (which it might not have gotten in its modified form), in this case the argument fails immediately: if the original author himself had made this change, there is no way we'd be debating whether the additional explanatory content was an acceptable change.

Comment: I've taken your community-wiki status as a cue to edit in arguments. If we get divergent "keep it" opinions (e.g., "we should keep it because authors have no right to their own answers" is a "keep it" opinion that is radically different from my own) then I suppose we'll need to split them into different answers.

Answer (score -8):

We should **rollback** to previous revision.

Comment: I want to support this answer, but only if, after a few weeks, several other paragraphs are added that explain the answer in greater detail.